# MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0 invalid characters

Tags: xml, parsing, lotusscript

I'm receiving the following error when parsing XML as answer from a webservice.

- An invalid character was found in text content.

The webservice sends answers with some characters as Ψ for example or HTML structured tests malformed with " or < and > characters.

The code used is:

```
Set var_xmlPostObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
Set var_xmlRequestDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set var_xmlResponseDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0")
'Send xml
Call var_xmlRequestDoc.loadXML(str_xml)
Dim var_pi As Variant
Set var_pi = var_xmlRequestDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'")
Call var_xmlRequestDoc.InsertBefore(var_pi, var_xmlRequestDoc.ChildNodes(0)) 'open the POST (or GET) connection to the web server
Call var_xmlPostObject.open("POST", str_soapPost, False)
Call var_xmlPostObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", str_soapType)
Call var_xmlPostObject.send(var_xmlRequestDoc.xml)
'Set response properties
var_xmlResponseDoc.async = False
var_xmlResponseDoc.validateOnParse = False
var_xmlResponseDoc.resolveExternals = False
Set var_xmlResponseDoc = var_xmlPostObject.responseXML
Print "var_xmlResponseDoc.xml: " & var_xmlResponseDoc.xml
If var_xmlResponseDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    'Alert
Else
    'Do something
End if
```

The question is if there's a way to detect the characters which brings the message before parse it? Some example would be very nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go for a differnt approach. Notes 8 allows you to natively consume a web service and just deal with some LotusScript (or Java classes). The core code will take care of encoding etc. so you don't need to deal with it. If for political reasons you are stuck on an outdated version of Lotus Notes you can use [Stubby][1] (the web service slayer) to generate the code. Much more reliable than the OLE connection.

[1]: http://www.nsftools.com/stubby/ Stubby